# Change font color of a column in rhandsontable

Tags: r, rstudio, rhandsontable

I have a table rendered using rhandsontable in R. I want to change the font color to red of a specific column. How can I do it ? I tried the following code, but it does not work

```
output$hot=renderRHandsontable({
rhandontable (table)%>%
hot_col("colum1", color = "red") 

})
```

Comment: I edited the code. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the style of elements inside of your table (in your case it is the font color of each cell of a given column), you will need to use a bit of Javascript and write a renderer function that will do the job, like so:

```
# Toy data frame
table <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])

# Custom renderer function
color_renderer <- "
  function(instance, td) {
    Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.style.color = 'red';
  }
"

rhandsontable(table) %>%
  hot_col("b", renderer = color_renderer)
```

The function `color_renderer()` is saved as a string and will be used as the `renderer` argument of the `hot_col()`-function. Note the argument *td* I am using refers to the cell object of your table. *td* has several attributes, one is the *style*, which in turn has the attribute *color*.
Also make certain that you are using the correct Handsontable renderer. In my case, it is a **TextRenderer** but you may use different renderers based on the data type your column has.

For more information, refer to the [Handsontable documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.13.0/tutorial-introduction.html).

I hope this helps.
Cheers

Comment: Is there a similar way to update the Column name row?